# Google Maps Key

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Eu tenho uma função que carrega a *API* do *Google Maps*, mas toda vez que eu tento mudar a *url*, seja para utilizar a minha key, ou até mesmo para adicionar a *library places* para poder utilizar os serviços de busca tenho problemas.

O função que estou a usar é esta:

```
function loadScript() {
     var script = document.createElement('script');
     script.type = 'text/javascript';
     script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' + 'callback=initialize';
     document.body.appendChild(script);
 };
```

Comment: Que tipo de problema?

Comment: O mapa desaparece.

Answer (score 0):

E acabou que consegui resolver o problema, aqui vai a solução caso alguém tenha algo parecido:

```
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' + 'libraries=places&' + 'callback=initialize';
```

Comment: Você não precisa concatenar a string nesse caso. Como não tem nenhum valor dinâmico, basta pegar a string direto mesmo. 

`script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&callback=initialize';`

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, criar um comando para carregar um script é meio complicado e pode custar o processamento. Nos meus scripts, eu sempre costumo chamar a API do Google Maps, seguido dos comandos `async` e `defer`. Esses comandos vão garantir que a API seja chamada em 2º plano, ou seja, enquanto você executa o seu HTML, a API será baixado "junto". Um exemplo de chamada com o `async defer` é esse:

> `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=init&libraries=places" async defer></script>`

Comment: Explicar com exemplos ajuda ainda mais a resposta. Como é uma resposta de uma pergunta bem antiga, talvez também seja legal a atualização da pergunta, caso tenha mudado bastante a chamada de função, código, etc.

Comment: Exato, faz mais de 1 ano que essa pergunta foi feita...